# Copying a worksheet from a file in a certain folder

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste, worksheet

I am trying to copy a worksheet from a file that is in a certain folder in my computer. I would like to have a main workbook (Workbook1) where I press a button that takes the 1st sheet from every xls or xlsm file from the certain folder (C:\Location). What I currently have is below.

```
Sub read_a_folder()

Dim MainWB As String

strPath = "C:\Location\"
MainWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Or objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xlsm" Then



End If
Next

End Sub
```

So im missing the way to copy the sheet as it is to my main workbook. I have tried using ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add but the special format of the copied sheets makes it unreadable. Ctrl+Shift+End and CTRL+C works when I do it manually.

Any help is much needed.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to follow up Dave's code (-> credits to him!) with some enhancements (and one little revision)

```
Option Explicit

Sub read_a_folder()

    Dim objFso As FileSystemObject
    Dim objFolder As Folder
    Dim objFile As File

    Dim MainWB As Workbook
    Dim strPath As String

    strPath = "C:\Location\"

    Set MainWB = ActiveWorkbook '<~~ Workbook is an object -> you must "Set" it

    Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False '<~~ this will reduce the flickering and speed it all up
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) Like "xls*" Then '<~~ use "Like" operator to check for all "xls..." extensions in a single check
            With Workbooks.Open(objFile.Path, False, True) '<~~ no need to set an object, just instantiate it and work with it! Furthermore let's use some of the "Open" method parameters to avoid prompts popping out
                .Worksheets(1).Copy After:=MainWB.Sheets(MainWB.Sheets.Count) 'copies after last worksheet
                .Close False
            End With
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True '<~~ turn screen updating on
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user3598756 (also thanks for @Dave). This works just like I hoped it would. Very helpful commenting also :)

Comment: you are welcome. but I only built on @Dave 's solution which I didn't want to edit and spoil it while comments would have been a cluttering way. so I ended up writing an answer to have things clear.  but Daves's the one to credit

Comment: @Dave Could you guys help me out here once more? Later in this program I would need to be able to detect which of my worksheets were added with this folder reading technique. Is it possible to add these worksheets as hidden? It would be helpful for me. (Im new to the site so I did not know should I comment here or post a new question).

Comment: just add `MainWB.ActiveSheet.Visible = False` statement before the `.Close False` one

Answer (score 0):

The following may help:

```
Sub read_a_folder()

Dim MainWB As Workbook
Dim objSheet As Worksheet

strPath = "C:\Location\"
MainWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFso.GetFolder(strPath)

For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    If objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xls" Or objFso.GetExtensionName(objFile.Path) = "xlsm" Then
        Set objWb = Workbooks.Open objFile.Path
        Set objSheet = objWb.Worksheets(1)  ' sets first sheet
        objSheet.Copy After:=MainWB.Sheets(MainWB.Sheets.Count) 'copies after last worksheet
        objWb.Close
        Set objSheet = Nothing
        Set objWb = Nothing
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: fine code. just some advices: A) `Dim MainWB As Workbook` declares (correctly) an object variable while `MainWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name` is wrong for two reasons: A1) it's not using `Set` keyword, mandatory to initialize objects A2) it's using `Workbook` `Name` property which wouldn't work should `Set` keyword be in place. B) the check on files extension would miss "xlsx" files... C) using plain `Open` method of `Workbooks` object could cause some prompt appearing with any "xlsm" file

Comment: @user3598756  You're right of course, I did spot A) and A2 initially but failed to correct them in the code I posted :)  For B I just went with the file types the OP had posted as they hadn't mentioned any other file types